# input sanitation for select option fields necessary?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Following situation: I have a form with mostly  dropdown lists which I populate from a database. There's also a text input field. The form is sent via POST.
What I'm wondering is, is it really necessary to sanitize the $_POST variables (besides the text input field, of course) before putting them in an sql query?
After all, it's not really user input if it came from a drop down list that I created. With $_GET I would understand the recommendation as it would be possible to manipulate the variables being sent. But AFAIK, that's not possible with POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faking a `POST` is as easy as faking a `GET`. So, YES, input sanitation is needed.

You can fake using `cURL` (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php), but it is even insanely easier to just edit a simple html page, copy & paste your code in it, replace the values of the dropdown with whatever value you want but keeping the address in the `action` property of the `form` tag, and then that form will send all that garbage to your unprotected script.

Comment: Copying the page onto your own (other) website server, and amending it, is certainly the easiest way to demonstrate the risk. It surprises me how most answers focus on "hacking tools" rather than this "developer approach".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, so you need to sanitize your database input.

With most browsers, it'll be difficult, but you can use tools like [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to simulate POST requests, where you have free control over the contents of the variables.